# procmail reciepe to remove mailing list tags from subject line

Tags: mailing-list, procmail

Most mailing lists prepend the subject line with a tag like f.e.

```
[name-of-the-mailing-list] Original subject line
```

How would I remove those tags in square brackets and eventually put them in an appropriate folder using a procmail recipe?

Answer (score 1):

I found out myself. This recipe will remove the tag:

```
:0 fwH
* ^subject:.*([name-of-the-mailing-list])
|sed -e 's/^Subject:[   ]\[name-of-the-mailing-list\]/Subject: /g'
```

This recipe will remove all tags:

```
:0 fwH
* ^subject:.*(\[[^]]*\])
|sed -e 's/^Subject:[   ]\[[^]]*\]/Subject: /g'
```